# How to set streetView in my mapview android application?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have another same questions on Stackoverflow, but the don't show any accepted answers !

How do I set streetView in my mapview ? I am using Google API platform 2.2 ?

Comment: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#setStreetView(boolean)

Comment: And since Peter's link doesn't resolve, here's one that works: http://goo.gl/ZcpQU

Comment: it's done work ?! ,, is street view available in USA or not !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setStreetView` method and give `on` as an argument to it.

Check this out:
[Street View](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#setStreetView%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StreetDetail extends FragmentActivity implements OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_street_detail);

    StreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment =  (StreetViewPanoramaFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.streetviewpanorama);
    streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {
    streetViewPanorama.setPosition(new LatLng(37.4083836,-122.1472079));
}
}
```

Add a fragment like this to your activity.

```
<fragment android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaFragment"
    android:id="@+id/streetviewpanorama"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />
```